# React Native Android getLaunchOptions using Android Restrictions

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm attempting to implement AppConfig on a React Native application.  The usecase is simple: I just need to allow the enterprise management tool to pass in a couple strings into the application.

I am able to setup the iOS version of the app to pass in these managed settings into the initial `props` of the application within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` call.  I'm looking to do the same with Android.

Here's what's in my MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    // Pukes because we can't do this before `onCreate()`
    final RestrictionsManager myRestrictionsMgr = (RestrictionsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE);

    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, "mynativeclient") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
            Timber.e("Launching with options");
            try {
                return myRestrictionsMgr.getApplicationRestrictions();
            } catch (NullPointerException nullptr) {
                Timber.e("Null pointer thrown at options");
                return null;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

This dies because I can't call the `getSystemServices` before `onCreate()`.  The `onCreate()` call is happening in the MainApplication.java file and I'm not entirely sure how to pass in items into the initial React Native props that way.

Here's an attempt in MainApplication.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final RestrictionsManager myRestrictionsMgr = (RestrictionsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE);
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
    }

    try {
        myRestrictionsMgr.getApplicationRestrictions();  << How do I pass that in?
    } catch (NullPointerException nullptr) {
        // Nom Nom nom
    }

    // Not sure what to do with this call...
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
}
```

How should I pass in the restrictions of an Android app into the base of a React Native and have it appear in the initial `props`?

Using `react-native@0.53.3` `react@16.3.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull your RestrictionsManager out as a member variable of your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    private RestrictionsManager restrictionsManager;
```

Then initialize it in your onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    restrictionsManager = (RestrictionsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE);
}
```

It should then be correctly initialized when React Native calls the createReactActivityDelegate()

Comment: This worked perfectly, I wasn't sure how you knew that `onCreate` existed as an override in the action but with the Bundle param this whole process worked out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    // the API appears to be providing a context in the ReactActivityDelegate constructor
    // assuming 'mynativeclient' is root component name
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, "mynativeclient") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
            Timber.e("Launching with options");
            RestrictionsManager myRestrictionsMgr = (RestrictionsManager) this.getSystemService(Context.RESTRICTIONS_SERVICE);
            Bundle restrictions = myRestrictionsMgr.getApplicationRestrictions();
            return restrictions;
        }
    };
}
```

You may have tried this. What error is thrown if any?

Comment: Yeah it seems the `getLaunchOptions` is static so there is no `this`.  The exact error is a compile error "Cannot resolve method this.getSystemService"